# Extract the values from a raster based on polygons and add those values directly to the polygon shapefile table in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, arcgis-10.3, zonal-statistics

I understand that the ZonalStatistics (ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools->Zonal->Zonal Statistics) in ArcGIS (10.3) allows the extraction of raster values within zones defined by a polygon shapefile (takes the average over the specified areas).  ZonalStatistics creates a new raster file based on the polygons.  I'd like to directly add the raster values to my polygon shapefile as a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the toolbox, exactly 1 tool below Zonal Statistics is a tool called Zonal Statistics as Table! This creates a table which you can then join back to your original polygon dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Add Surface information will add values from a raster to the attribute table of a polygon feature class.  This tool requires a 3D Analyst toolbox and an advanced license.